# Is there a closed formula for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I was asked to find a closed formula for the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\binom{n}{k}$$

could anyone give me an advice on how to get started?

Comment: Hint: expand the binomal coefficient $\binom nk$ using factorials.

Comment: We get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: That's correct. Now this almost looks like another binomial coefficient, doesn't it ? Try to write it as a binomial coefficient by multiplying it by something that depends on $n$ only.

Comment: gotcha :D thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k!}{k!(k+1)(k+2)}\binom{n}{k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k!}{(k+2)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
\\=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}
\\=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n+2)!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}
\\=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+2}{k+2}$$
then you can complete using $(1+x)^n=\sum {{n}\choose{k}} x^k$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\mbox{Lets consider}\quad\fermi\pars{x}\equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{x^{k + 2} \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}}\,{n \choose k}\,,\quad
\fermi\pars{0} =0\,,\quad\fermi\pars{1} = {\large ?}
$$

> $$
> \fermi'\pars{x}=
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{x^{k + 1} \over k + 1}\,{n \choose k}\,,\qquad
> \fermi'\pars{0} = 0
> $$

$$
\fermi''\pars{x}=
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}x^{k}{n \choose k}=\pars{1 + x}^{n}\qquad\imp\qquad
\fermi'\pars{x}={\pars{1 + x}^{n + 1} - 1\over n + 1}
$$

> $$
> \imp\qquad\fermi\pars{x}=
> {1 \over n + 1}\,{\pars{1 + x}^{n + 2} - 1 \over n + 2} - {x \over n + 1}
> $$

$$
\fermi\pars{1}
=\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}\pars{k + 2}}\,
{n \choose k}
={2^{n + 2} - n - 3 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Start with $(1+x)^n=\sum {{n}\choose{k}} x^k$ . If you integrate this twice wrt x you will get something close to what you are after.

Comment: You won by half a second ! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Sure - you know that $(1 + x)^n = \sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} x^k$ from which it follows that 
$$
\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}
= \int (1 + x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x 
= \int \sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} x^k \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} \int x^k \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} .
$$
Based on what I've shown, you can iterate on this method, and allow $x$ to become a certain number, which should give you the closed form you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k = (1+x)^n$$ Integrate twice both rhs and lhs with respect to $x$ and when finished, plug $x=1$ in your result.

Comment: There is no need of integration here.

Comment: In "mathematic" house are many mansions (adaptation of John 14:2)

Comment: I do agree with that, but one may enter into the house without keys to all mansions.