# Sum of $\frac{C_r}{(r+1)(r+2)}$ from $r=0$ to $r=n$

Tags: integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am trying to compute the following sum: $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{C_r}{(r+1)(r+2)}$$

Integrating $(1+x)^n = \sum_{r=0}^{n}C_rx^r$ with respect to $x$,
$$\int(1+x)^n dx=\int\sum_{r=0}^{n}C_rx^rdx$$
$$\implies \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}C_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$$

Again integrating with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$ yields,
$$\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{r=0}^{n}C_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}dx$$

$$\implies\bigg[\frac{(1+x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\bigg]_0^1=\bigg[\sum_{r=0}^{n}C_r\frac{x^{r+2}}{(r+1)(r+2)}\bigg]_0^1$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{C_r}{(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{2^{n+2}-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

But it is written in my textbook that the answer is $$\frac{2^{n+2}-(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

So, where am I going wrong? Is it correct to use integral twice in such situations?

Comment: Your first integration is not quite right. Try putting $x=0$ on both sides. You forgot to fix the integration constant (or integrate from 0 to $x$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\binom{n}{k}=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667156/sum-k-0n-frac1k1k2-binomnk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to respect the *[integration constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration)* when evaluating an indefinite integral.

> When calculating $\int(1+x)^n\,dx = \int\sum_{r=0}^nC_rx^r\,dx$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \int(1+x)^n\,dx&=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+K_1\\
> \int\sum_{r=0}^nC_rx^r\,dx&=\sum_{r=0}^nC_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}+K_2
> \end{align*}
>   with $K_1,K_2$ constants.

It follows
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^nC_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\color{blue}{+K}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $K=K_2-K_1$.

By setting $x=0$ in (1) we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n+1}=K}
\end{align*}

> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^nC_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{n+1}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Integrating (2) from $0$ to $1$ gives now the correct result
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\int_{0}^1\sum_{r=0}^nC_r\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\,dx}&=\int_{0}^1\left(\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\,dx\\
> &=\left[\frac{(1+x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{x}{n+1}\right]_0^1\\
> &=\left[\frac{2^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]-\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{2^{n+2}-(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}}
> \end{align*}
>   as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is correct because also we have:
$$\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n+2}{r}=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left(2^{n+2}-1-(n+2)\right)$$

Comment: Shouldnt there be -2 instead of -1

Comment: It should be $-\binom{n+2}{0}-\binom{n+2}{1}=-1-(n+2).$

Comment: If summation starts from r=0 then it is correct